# Picklist value Validation

Tags: salesforce, formula, picklist

I am trying to create a validation off a pick list value if "In Person".

IF the picklist value= in-person and product type is Home Equity or Jr Home Equity add a box for provided disclosures yes or no

Any thoughts? Is this possible

Help creating a formula

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your product field is a picklist and your disclosures field is a checkbox:

```
and( ispickval(Picklist_Field__c,'In-Person'),
    or( ispickval(Product_Type__c, 'Home Equity'),
        ispickval(Product_Type__c, 'Jr Home Equity')),
    Provided_Disclosures=false )
```